# Multiple 'root to' routes in rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to get rails to go to different controller#action according to the subdomain, and this is what I have so far in routes.rb

```
Petworkslabs::Application.routes.draw do

  get '/', to: 'custom#show', constraints: {subdomain: '/.+/'}, as: 'custom_root'
  get '/',  to: "welcome#home", as: 'default_root'
end
```

rake shows the correct routes I want it to take

```
rake routes
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern             Controller#Action
 custom_root GET    /                       custom#show {:subdomain=>"/.+/"}
default_root GET    /                       welcome#home
```

But for some reason, I can't get requests like abc.localhost:3000 to hit the custom controller. It always routes it to welcome#home. Any ideas? I am fairly new to rails, so any tips about general debugging would also be appreciated.

EDIT: I stepped through the code using the debugger and this is what I found

(rdb:32) request.domain
"abc.localhost"
(rdb:32) request.subdomain
""
(rdb:32) request.subdomain.present?
false

Looks like for some reason rails thinks that the subdomain is not present, even though its there. I wonder if its because I am doing this localhost.

Comment: Why doing you load a home and on the controller you can make that redirect

Comment: @mZaragoza , I don't follow what you are suggesting. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: i get to your app with any sub-doamin. application controller loads and from there you can determine what sub-doamin i came from and then you can redirect me to the proper place

Comment: @mZaragoza, yeah, I could do that, but it feels like a hack to me. If rails has a way to route using the in-built routing mechanism, I would rather use that.

Comment: I would agree but i dont know if you can make a decision in the routes files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason request.subdomain was not getting populated at all (I suspect this is because I have doing this on localhost, I have opened a bug here https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12438). This was causing the regex match in routes.rb to fail. I ended up creating a custom matches? method for Subdomain which looks something like this

```
class Subdomain
  def self.matches?(request)

    request.domain.split('.').size>1 && request.subdomain != "www"
  end
end
```

and hooking that up in routes.rb

```
constraints(Subdomain) do
  get '/',  to: "custom#home", as: 'custom_root'
end
```

this seems to work.

EDIT: More information in the github issues page https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12438

Answer (score 7):

**Updated Answer:**

Worked for me on Rails 3 & 4:

```
get '/' => 'custom#show', :constraints => { :subdomain => /.+/ }
root :to => "welcome#home"
```

Comment: No luck..it always tries to route to custom#show for every thing :(

Comment: See my updated answer.  Works on  my local machine.  Going to http://localhost takes me to a different page than going to http://test.localhost.

Comment: Hmm this is what I tried before with no luck... Are you on rails 4.0?

Comment: I modified my answer for Rails 4 (get instead of match) and now it works on both Rails 3 and 4.

Comment: Aha!!!!  You've got your regex in single quotes, so it's being processed as a string a not a regex.  Copy my code without the single quotes and it should work.

Comment: Sorry, no idea.  Works like a charm on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

@manishie's answer is right, but you'll still likely have issues in your devo environment if you're using `localhost`. To fix it add the following line to `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 0
```

and then use @manishie's answer in `routes.rb`:

```
get '/' => 'custom#show', :constraints => { :subdomain => /.+/ }
root :to => "welcome#home"
```

The issue is that tld_length defaults to 1 and there's no domain extension when you're using localhost so rails fails to pickup the subdomain. pixeltrix explains it really well here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12438