# Overwrite root route in rails 4 for a certain subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, constraints

I'd like so overwrite my `root :to => redirect("/projects")` route if the subdomain is equal to "www" or is just "". This means if the subdomain is "www" or "" the app should use my `website#index` controller/action.

At the moment I got this setup:

```
class Subdomain
  def self.match(r)
    r.subdomain == "www" || r.subdomain == ""
  end
end
```

.....

```
# website
scope :constraints => lambda { |request| Subdomain.match(request) } do
  get '/' => 'website#index'
  get "/help" => "website#help", as: "help"
  get "/about" => "website#about", as: "about"
  get "/signup" => "website#signup", as: "signup"
  # post "/signup" => "website#signup_account"
end

root :to => redirect("/projects")
```

If I access www.satisfy.dev/help or satisfy.dev/help everything works fine. If I access www.satisfy.dev/ or satisfy.dev/ the root_path (/projects) is in use. I thought the `get '/' => 'website#index'` should be more important than the root_path since it's above the root_path.

Hope somebody has a hint for me!

Comment: would it work to put another `root :to` inside the scope?

Comment: Naw, than I get the following error: `ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'root' You may have defined two routes with the same name using the ':as' option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming.` :/

Answer (score 0):

I tried treating the routes as "get" requests and had more success.

See here: 
[Multiple 'root to' routes in rails 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171428/multiple-root-to-routes-in-rails-4-0)